# JMeter - Simple Table Server - Cannot start using "simple-table-server.cmd"

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We are trying to start SimpleTableServer by running `Simple-table-server.cmd` script located in your JMETER_HOME/bin directory.

We are getting below exception, please suggest a solution

`c:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin>simple-table-server.cmd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass(LoggingManager.java:122)
at org.jmeterplugins.protocol.http.control.HttpSimpleTableServer.(HttpSimpleTableServer.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
...`

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing dependency in cmd file

You can edit file to add slf4j-api-1.7.25, change:

```
set CP=..\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_core.jar;..\lib\jorphan.jar;..\lib\ext\jmeter-plugins-table-server-2.2.jar
```

To:

```
set CP=..\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_core.jar;..\lib\jorphan.jar;..\lib\ext\jmeter-plugins-table-server-2.2.jar;..\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
```

This will make it work.

You can post the issue in [Jmeter plugin group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins)