# StartAgent-2.2.3 isn't staring for Server Monitoring in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, perfmon

I'm trying to do Server Performance Testing in Jmeter - 5.4.2 via PerfMon - 2.3. But when I try to run the bat file of startAgent - 2.2.3 it just opens for one moment and them closes (Note that I've JRE version 1.8 installed). When I tried to open the file via cmd directory command it's giving me the following error:

---

> `ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

---

- I've tried to install the 2.2 version of startAgent.
- I've tried to put the startAgent in the same directory as JMeter.
- I've tried start it by disabling Firewall and Anti-Virus.

But nothing is working. I tried to do some related research regarding this error but there isn't many solution that I have found to be useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JMeter - Simple Table Server - Cannot start using "simple-table-server.cmd"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806485/jmeter-simple-table-server-cannot-start-using-simple-table-server-cmd)

Comment: Thank You for taking your time to answer my query. But I don't understand in which file I've to make the explained changes. So I'm afraid but the mentioned post doesn't answer my query.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue when I tried unzipping the server-agent folder elsewhere so I unzipped it in a folder in C drive (C:\Jmeter) and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).